# My form input-fields don't work with Materializecss

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, materialize

I'm using the Devise gem for rails 4 and I try to add a radio button and a pulldown to my /registrations/edit.html.erb view. Next to that I'm using Material Design, which seems to disable these functions as well

It works fine if I disable Material Design (I'm able to update these new fields for my Devise user), but when I turn it on again (`@import "materialize";` in `application.scss`) they are both not clickable, but the rest of the form does work though.

So here's my code.

application.scss:

```
//= require morris

@import "materialize";
@import "toastr";
```

/registrations/edit.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 m6 offset-m3 center">
<h5>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h5>
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: "shared/devisemes" %>

  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.radio_button :sex, 1 %> <%= f.label :sex, "Female" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :sex, 2 %> <%= f.label :sex, "Male" %>
  </div>

  <br/>
  <div class="input-field">
  <%= f.label :country_code, "Default Config" %>
  <%= f.country_select :country_code %>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, :class => "validate", :placeholder => "Name" %>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.email_field :email, :class => "validate", :placeholder => "Email" %>
  </div>

    <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
      <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
    <% end %>

  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.password_field :password, :id => "password", :placeholder => "New password (leave blank if you don't want to change it)", :class => "validate", autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :id => "password_confirmation", :placeholder => "Confirm password", :class => "validate", autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field">
    <%= f.password_field :current_password, :id => "current_password", :placeholder => "Type current password to confirm your change", :class => "validate", autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Update</button>
  <%= link_to "Back", :back, :class => "btn waves-effect waves-light" %>
<% end %>

<br/>
<p>Unhappy?</p>
<%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete, :class => "btn waves-effect waves-light" %>
```

The items that aren't working in the above code are `:sex` and `:country_code`.

And here is what it looks like in my browser (Name and country overlap as well and gender/sex and Country select aren't reacting at all):
[image: Name and country overlap as well and gender/sex and Country select aren't reacting at all]

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you don't actually want class `input-field` on radio buttons or select fields. From the [documentation](http://materializecss.com/forms.html):

> "Text fields allow user input. The border should light up simply and clearly indicating which field the user is currently editing. You must have a .input-field div wrapping your input and label. This helps our jQuery animate the label. This is only used in our Input and Textarea form elements."

For the select functionality, the documentation says to wrap it in an `.input-field` (that contradicts the quote above, whoops!). It seems to be working for me WITHOUT the wrapper class. The thing you do need to make sure to do is:

`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').material_select();
});`

This is mentioned at the very bottom of the select field documentation section. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, that helps! The country selection menu works now. Thanks!!
But this doesn't work for the radio buttons. I removed the `input-field` for these as well, but they are still not selectable. Any tips on what I could be doing wrong in that specific case?

Comment: Materialize is really picky about needing the labels to all map really well to the radio buttons. Make sure you provide the value in the label. I'm using a partial for my radio buttons (I have a lot!), and it looks like this:
`
<%= f.radio_button(key, value) %>
<%= f.label(key, text, value: value) %>
`
I believe an example for your data would look like: key: `:sex`, value: `1`, and text: `Female`. You want to make sure the label matches the radio button id.